# Can a Application hosted on GAE reach local tomcat on my pc

Tags: rest, google-app-engine, tomcat

I have one application deployed on Google App Engine and another application hosted on my local machine on top of tomcat.

So my question is , can we reach the application on the tomcat ( App URL http://localhost:8080/xyz)  from the Application which is hosted on Google App Engine.

Comment: If your local box has a dedicated IP yes. But if you are just using a internet service and relying on it , it won't work. Other means of communication is to call your app engine APIs from local tomcat on regular intervals . Or app engine can send email to your mail box and your local tomcat can poll on the email box for latest emails and then do its work. Just few options.

Answer (score 0):

App Engine applications can communicate with other applications or access other resources on the web by fetching URLs. An app can use the URL Fetch service to issue HTTP and HTTPS requests and receive responses. The URL Fetch service uses Google's network infrastructure for efficiency and scaling purposes.

So, yes, you can access your Tomcat application running on-premises using AppEngine's URLFetch class. It is available for all sandbox supported languages such as [Python](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/), [Java](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/) and [Go](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/urlfetch/).

Here is simplified example with Python:

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch

url = "http://my-tomcat-app.com/"
result = urlfetch.fetch(url)
if result.status_code == 200:
  doSomethingWithResult(result.content)
```